# Overflow effect as in photoshop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to make an overlay effect like the photoshop or illustrator effects.

I have a picture as background and in front I am putting a div with a color background, and I would like to apply an overlay effect  over the front div (like in PS or Illustrator),  which actually looks better than the simple transparency effect.

Do you know any way to do this? maybe using any JS library?

Thanks in advance, for your help.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "overlay" effect? There are so many effects that use two images above each other...

Comment: I mean the multiply, overlay, color burn and all that kind of effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.pixastic.com/

Not sure if it will do what you want but worth a look.

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/

Comment: Wow yeah, thats just what I was looking for, I am going to read the documentation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

if overlay effect like you want is like to show transparent effect then try this

http://ajaxdump.com/2009/09/02/image-overlay-effect-using-jquery/

or

http://tommcfarlin.com/simple-overlay/

actually there is a more tutorial of overlay effect using jquery ( js library ) like what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to blend modes in PS/AI, then no, those kinds of blending options aren't available in HTML/CSS - yet. [Certain filter like effects](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/css-filters.php) are coming, but not the blending modes (to my knowledge).